# Schottky diodes or regular ones for input protection circuit

Tags: diodes, protection

Which ones would you use for protecting a low voltage signal input (digital)? Schottky or regular? I plan on using it in this configuration:

[image: this configuration]

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Super-barrier diodes offer the same speed/low-forward voltage drop as schottkys, but have better leakage characteristics. The ones I have seen have been more expensive than schottky diodes, but if power is at a premium in your design (battery powered?) it may well be worth the additional expense.

Answer (score 0):

All CMOS use this configuration using Schottky diodes to protect every input. But they are small diodes and limited to 15mA continuous current.

Comment: Really? I would have thought that the [high leakage current of Schottky diodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode#Limitations) would wreck one of the advantages of CMOS.

Comment: It would, if Schottky diodes were used. But, at least for CMOS, they're not.

Comment: I was actually talking about external circuitry... Not the internal clamping diodes in microcontrollers and such.